# CSS width, deactivate resizing right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to get ride of the responsiveness of my bootstrap theme I set the the width to 970px on every container classes in the bootstrap.css. But when I shrink the page the blocks resize... 
I would like to kind of make it like Google or Facebook that when you shrink the page it just cut's in in the middle, instead of resizing. 
Example of what I want but cannot achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8tes.png Here is an image example.
 And a second one here if you don't understand. https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7nwf.jpg

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have been trying for hours to achieve this with no success thank you. I you need any bit's of code please tell me, I wasn't sure which fill to insert.

I hope this post does not violate any rules. Thank you!

Comment: Have you changed the width at all the breakpoints?

Comment: What are breakpoints exactly? I wasn't too sure when I was reading how to deactivate responsiveness. @Guy

Comment: Breakpoints are the sizes at which certain styles will be applied. For example in bootstrap at several sizes - 1200, 992 and 768px - the width of the container is changed. To stop the resizing as you mentioned in your question, you would need to override those media queries. See my answer below for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the width at all the breakpoints. Bootstrap sets the width at various window widths.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

All of those will need to be updated to your new fixed width to stop it resizing. E.g.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
      .container {
        width: 970px;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .container {
        width: 970px;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container {
        width: 970px;
      }
    }
```

Note, this should be done in your .css file, not in the bootstrap one.

Comment: No problem. Please could you mark it as correct so other people will be able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decorating the CSS attributes with an !important?   That may address the issue.

If that does not work you should be able to consult the developer tools in Chrome or IE11+ or Firefox Firebug, you should be able to see what class is setting the width.

PS: You may want to step back question why you are even using Bootstrap as it sounds like you are disabling its main featureset.

Comment: I have added the `!Important` tag everywhere that I set the width, I am using bootstrap because the theme I used run's under bootstrap.

Comment: See @Guy's answer above.   But again, you should revisit your use of Bootstrap.  You are using a sledgehammer to kill a flea -- when it sounds like you want to kill a gnat.